# Implementing Checkpointing in Spark Streaming Job submitted using Spark Job Server

Tags: spark-streaming, spark-jobserver, checkpointing

Implementing checkpointing when spark streaming job is diretcly submitted to spark seems straight forward . We are a facing quite some complexities when we need to the same when the streaming job is submitted using Spark Job server..any pointers/reference could be quite helpful. Can anybody help?

Comment: What is the difference in two approaches?

Comment: @noorul when you submit a spark streaming job using SJS you do not create the StreamingContext in the job implementation. but receive it as a parameter into the overridden runJob method https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/job-server-extras/src/main/scala/spark/jobserver/StreamingTestJob.scala

Comment: If you look at the implementation it is actually returning a StreamingContext https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/job-server-extras/src/main/scala/spark/jobserver/context/StreamingContextFactory.scala#L18

Comment: @noorul I am unsure how it is helpful. Can you add more details?